# Adding spreadsheet information to KML

Tags: kml, excel, spreadsheet

I have a KML from [Indy Neighborhoods ArcGIS](https://arc-gis-hub-home-arcgishub.hub.arcgis.com/datasets/d5b4734bed3f49f9b2109ca9a0401886_10?geometry=-87.451%2C39.595%2C-84.814%2C39.965). I have the results of a factor analysis based on neighborhood traits from savi.org. From this, I did a clustering. I would like to combine the contents of the clustering outcome spreadsheet, consisting of cluster, color, and scores of factors, to the KML.

How would I do this?

Comment: Which software are you working with? What have you tried? Are there common IDs or spatial overlaps?

Comment: Excel and wordpad. I don't know what software exists. I ultimately want to publish it as an overlay on google maps within a frame. The KML is from the county government, so I presume that it's clean regarding unique IDs and no overlaps.

Comment: I have found a LOT of utilities that allow me to add point data, but that isn't what I need. I need to attach data to polygons, some of which have a very large number of coordinates.